# WPF databinding and refreshing its UI

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

I've posted the same question before but it wasn't clear (and contained too many self-induced errors in attempt to fix the code) so re-posting it with more details.

So I have "MainUiWindow.xaml" file which uses databinding like this:

```
            <ItemsControl x:Name="gridSettingsMonster" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" ItemsSource="{Binding SettingsMonster}">
                <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>                        
                    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type core:Setting}">
                        <Grid x:Name="gridMonster">
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding Label}" IsEnabled="{Binding Enabled}" ToolTip="{Binding Description}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="10 5 10 5" FontWeight="{Binding Fontweight}" ></TextBlock>
                            <ts:ToggleSwitch x:Name="toggleSwitchMonsterAll" IsEnabled="{Binding Enabled}" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Command ="{Binding TriggerAction}" IsChecked="{Binding Value}" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="5 0 20 2" Foreground="White" UncheckedText="" CheckedText="" UncheckedBorderBrush="#FF333333" CheckedBorderBrush="#FF2D2D30"/>
                        </Grid>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            </ItemsControl>
```

SettingsMonster binding:

```
        SettingsMonster.Add(new Setting(ConfigHelper.Main.Values.Overlay.MonsterWidget.IsVisible, true, "Monster_1", "Monster Widget", "Show/Hide Monsters Widget", new Command(_ =>
       {
           ConfigHelper.Main.Values.Overlay.MonsterWidget.IsVisible = !ConfigHelper.Main.Values.Overlay.MonsterWidget.IsVisible;
           ConfigHelper.Main.Save();
       })));


        SettingsMonster.Add(new Setting(ConfigHelper.Main.Values.Overlay.MonsterWidget.ShowUnchangedMonsters, ConfigHelper.Main.Values.Overlay.MonsterWidget.IsVisible,  "Monster_2", "    Show unchanged monsters", "Automatically hide monsters if they are not damaged", new Command(_ =>
       {
           ConfigHelper.Main.Values.Overlay.MonsterWidget.ShowUnchangedMonsters = !ConfigHelper.Main.Values.Overlay.MonsterWidget.ShowUnchangedMonsters;
           ConfigHelper.Main.Save();
       })));
```

And finally, the Setting class:

```
 public class Setting 
    {
        public bool Value { get; set; }
        public bool Enabled { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; }
        public string Label { get; }
        public string Description { get; }
        public string Checkbox_visibility { get; }
        public string Fontweight { get; }
        public List<Setting>SubSettings { get; }
        public Command TriggerAction { get; }
        public Setting(bool value, bool enabled, string name, string label, string description, Command action = null)
        {
            Value = value;
            Enabled = enabled;
            Name = name;
            Label = label;
            Description = description;                       
            SubSettings = new List<Setting>(); 
            TriggerAction = action;            
        }
    }
```

**Problem:**
When I run the build and use the "ToggleSwitch" (it's basically a open-source checkbox) to change the value of "ConfigHelper.Main.Values.Overlay.MonsterWidget.IsVisible", it unchecks the UI correctly.
I want this checkbox to control the other checkboxes (i.e. "Monster_2") as well, so that when the main one is turned off, set IsEnabled value for the child checkboxes/textblocks to FALSE.
I got to the stage where if I check off the main one, restart the build, then the child checkboxes/textblocks are all set as IsEnabled=False. However, I want the same to happen in real time (i.e. refresh the UI without having to restart).

Any help would be appreciated.

**EDIT 1.**

So I have attempted implementing the INotifyPropertyChanged in my Settings class which looks like the following:

```
public class Setting : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        private bool _value;
        private bool _enabled;
        
        public bool Value
        {
            get
            {
                return _value;
            }
            set
            {
                if (_value == value)
                    return;
                _value = value;
                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Enabled));

            }
        }
        public bool Enabled
        {
            get
            {
                return _enabled;
            }
            set
            {
                if (_enabled == value)
                    return;
                _enabled = value;
                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Enabled));

            }
        }

        protected void OnPropertyChanged(string name)
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
            {
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
            }                
        }

        public string Name { get; }
        public string Label { get; }
        public string Description { get; }
        public string Checkbox_visibility { get; }
        public string Fontweight { get; }
        public List<Setting>SubSettings { get; }
        public Command TriggerAction { get; }
        public Setting(bool value, bool enabled, string name, string label, string description, Command action = null)
        {
            Value = value;
            Enabled = enabled;
            Name = name;
            Label = label;
            Description = description;                       
            SubSettings = new List<Setting>(); 
            TriggerAction = action;            
        }
```

But my UI is still not refreshing yet... any help?

Comment: Try implementing INotifyPropertychanged in setting type.

Comment: Tried implementing INotifyPropertychanged in setting type... but still not refreshing. My changes are added in EDIT1.

Comment: There's a mistake in your `INotifyPropertyChanged` implementation for the `Value` property. You call `OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Enabled))` when it looks like it should be `OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Value))`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My viewmodel was referencing incorrect variable in the first place.
I have implemented INotifyPropertyChange in my Setting object as below, and also added a command to be run when the checkbox is triggered.

```
public class Setting : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected void OnPropertyChanged(string name)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
        }
    }

    private bool _value;
    private bool _enabled;
    
    public bool Value
    {
        get
        {
            return _value;
        }
        set
        {
            if (_value == value)
                return;
            _value = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Value));
        }
    }
    public bool Enabled
    {
        get
        {
            return _enabled;
        }
        set
        {
            if (_enabled == value)
                return;
            _enabled = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Enabled));
        }
    }

   
    public string Name { get; }
    public string Label { get; }
    public string Description { get; }        
    public string Fontweight { get; }
    public List<Setting>SubSettings { get; }
    public Command TriggerAction { get; }
    public Setting(bool _value, bool _enabled, string name, string label, string description, Command action = null)
    {
        Value = _value;
        Enabled = _enabled;
        Name = name;
        Label = label;
        Description = description;                       
        SubSettings = new List<Setting>(); 
        TriggerAction = action;            
    }                
}
```